# Is there a Dapp for an Escrow(like) Smart Contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, etherscan

I have been searching and can't tell if I'm just confused or what. But I am trying to find out if there is a Dapp or if i need to make a smart contract that allows me to make an escrow smart contract or something of the likes. I am looking for this because I am trying to make a large purchase from a seller I have not necessarily gained a lot of trust yet and want the payment to go through on delivery of the goods.

Comment: Please check this article on Medium 'https://medium.com/@pranav.89/smart-contracting-simplified-escrow-in-solidity-ethereum-b19761e8fe74'. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: https://bcshop.io/. This platform supports escrow deals and payments on Ethereum blockchain.